# React Native - React Navigation Cannot use Hooks in DrawerContent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I am developing an e-commerce application using **React Native** and I am trying to use **useState** in the **drawerContent** and it tells me this

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Here's the code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import IonIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"
import { categories } from '../../../services/DataTest'
import DrawerSearch from './DrawerSearch'
import DrawerItem from './DrawerItem'

export default function DrawerContent (props) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.customDrawerTouch}
            >
                <View style={styles.backButtonRow}>
                    <IonIcons
                        name="ios-arrow-back"
                        size={25}
                        style={styles.customDrawerIcon}
                        color="#666666"
                    />
                    <Text style={{ color: '#666666' }}>Back to Components</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <DrawerSearch value={search} setValue={setSearch}/>
            <FlatList
                data={categories}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={DrawerItem}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    customDrawerTouch: {
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        paddingLeft: 13,
        paddingTop: 15,
    },
    customDrawerIcon: {
        paddingRight: 10
    },
    backButtonRow: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingBottom: 17,
        paddingLeft: 3,
        borderBottomColor: '#F0F0F0',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    },
});
```

I'm using this component here

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HeaderCategorie from '../../components/categories/index/HeaderCategorie';
import SearchBar from '../../components/home/index/SearchBar';
import DrawerContent from '../../components/categories/index/DrawerContent';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function CategoriesScreen({ navigation }) {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <HeaderCategorie navigation={navigation}/>
            <View style={styles.headerSearch}>
                <SearchBar />
            </View>
            
        </View>
    )
}

export default function Categories() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Categories"
            drawerContent={DrawerContent}
            screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    },
    headerSearch: {
        marginVertical:10
    },
    headerSearchText: {
        fontWeight:"bold",
        fontSize:35,
        marginLeft:20,
        marginVertical:15,
    }
});
```

Comment: as what it says, you might have some dependency version issue. Delete `node_modules` and do `npm install` again.

Comment: I just tried that and still the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason: By using `drawerContent={DrawerContent}`, you are actually passing the reference of the `DrawerContent` function, which ends up breaking [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

So to resolve this, change the following line:

```
     <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Categories"
            drawerContent={DrawerContent}
            screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}
        >
```

to this

```
     <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Categories"
            drawerContent={(props)=> <DrawerContent {...props}/>} // here
            screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}
        >
```

[demo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@moistbobo/so-69236983)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understood my mistake :)

Comment: but i thought `DrawerContent` is a function component which hasn't been invoked yet. How's the change would make it work?

Comment: @windmaomao I had a look at the issues in the react-navigation repo and found [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7725#issuecomment-595795543). 

From my understanding, It seems like the reason is that `drawerContent` has to be a render function, not an actual function component. But I can't find any official documentation that differentiates the two.

Comment: @Moistbobo, thanks i missed that part `(props)`, so it's a render function. Man, maybe this is how router uses as well. Makes sense, thank you very much!!