# when I'm using DrawerItemList the app crashes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a drawer menu using react navigation. I want to use a custom DrawerContent, and when I'm using the  the app crashes with this error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.routes')". If I comment this specific line the app just run.

This is my DrawerContent:

```
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function DrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView
        {...props}
        contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#000" }}
      >
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js(where the navigation is):

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./src/screens/Home.js";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import DrawerContent from "./src/components/DrawerContent.js";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={() => <DrawerContent />}
        initialRouteName="Home"
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
        ></Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: Can you also share top-level component? I cannot see `state.routes` here.

Comment: the top-level component would be where I use the navigation container for example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting `DrawerItemList` to receive a full set of props from `Drawer.Navigator`, but you're passing it to `Drawer.Navigator` wrapped in a function that discards all the props it receives:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={() => <DrawerContent />} // <-- no props passed to DrawerContent
  initialRouteName="Home"
>
```

You need to pass through all props:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />} // <-- pass in the props
  initialRouteName="Home"
>
```

---

Note that you might think you can just pass in the function component to the prop, like this, which looks functionally identical to the above:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={DrawerContent} // <-- will fail with "rules of hooks" errors
  initialRouteName="Home"
>
```

...but this will fail with "Invalid hook call" errors if it's a functional component that contains hooks, because [`drawerContent` prop treats the passed-in function as a render function, not a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69237276).

Answer (score 1):

I tried every possible way to solve this error but at last just after restarting my computer i solved the error. Hope it works for you also